# Why in firebug there are lots of Inherited parts for one element from * { }?

Tags: css, styles, universal

As picture below shows, I see lots of Inherited parts from * selector (universal selector):
[image]

Is there any inefficiency in the way I wrote the code? Should I do something to prevent such situation or is it normal?

**EDIT:**
I see the same situation for G+:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With * you select every element. Then every child inherits some attributes of their parent-tags. This is why you got the very long inheritance list.

Something must be wrong, I don't get this long list. Please try [this](http://www.paul-muench-haus-ruchheim.de/Veran/veran2012.html).

Comment: Is it inefficient? If answer is positive what if I want to apply font-size to all elements or a universal color to all elements?

Comment: Long inheritance is gone, but the link you provided does not have much inner elements!

Comment: Back to the question: I don't **think** that this is inefficient. The rules are only applied once. Mozilla doesn't say that many css rules are inefficient ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS )

Comment: What's the link in your answer supposed to be? I can't read German.

Comment: Its a list of Events at a local library.